# Explain Time dilation for me with many easy to comprehend examples and reasons

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, time-dilation, faster-than-light

I can’t wrap my head around this.

So didn’t Einstein came to believe time stops because he imagined watching a clock tower as he raced away in a near light speed train? He would then notice that the light will reach him slower and thus time would APPEAR to be slowing down due to the clock ticking slowly but surely it’s an illusion?  Oh and don’t tell me about two planes flying opposite directions and gps. I know about that.

Anyway. So what if I go near speed light and time for me slows, but shouldn’t I see time slow on the outside also? Since there’s no preferred frame. What if a warp ship that can keep up with me by warping space rather than traveling near light speed was next to my ship at 0.999% c. How would I appear to be moving inside the ship? Slowly? Quickly?

What if I went to Alpha Centauri at 0.999%c? Let’s say I engage engines in earth orbit, what would it look like on earth to watch my ship go at near speed of light? Once I arrive 4.4 years will pass on earth, but let’s say they sent radio signals every day towards me as I traveled. When I arrive at alpha cen, would I hear the radio signals sent on the day I launched? And if I travel back to earth at c, if I was going fast enough for a 20 day journey time from my frame, what kind of radio signals would I pick up? From what year on earth that radio messages were sent would I pick up in my 20 day journey time that takes 4.4 years earth time? Would I be intercepting the signal at twice the speed of light or would it come to me at c regardless? If so, please give me a timeline of which messages I would hear first when I arrive to alpha cen and when I leave back to earth. And how could I travel in the direction of oncoming light but only measure light at c? Are you saying the closing speed wouldn’t be twice c? What? If I shine headlights while going near c on earth would it look like a light beam coming out also at c, barely pulling ahead of me? But in my ship I’d see light go out at c because my time slows down so that light can make that journey to reach the distance of 1 light second ahead of me because I’m near c??

Also how does length contract? It makes no sense and violates physics. How is length shortened? It literally makes no fkn sense that my length is shortened and the universe is shorter for me but everyone else sees it “normally”.

If time nearly stands still at 0.99999999% c or whatever, and I travel that fast to a point of light, would that point of light appear still or appear to move very fast? Let’s say time is “near frozen” at super speeds for me, wouldn’t I fly towards a point that is frozen time only to arrive and realize it’s not even there at all (and this is taking to account where it would be in its orbit depending on how far it is and would have moved the time it’s light reached me )? At that rate how could you ever fly somewhere accurately if time nearly freezes and all the stars stop and when u slow down they suddenly jump to a new location.

What if two of us are different ships and I’m moving at 0.99999999% c while the other ship goes 0.99% c. Who would appear to be slowing down or moving faster? How could length contract more for a person a few meters apart ? If one of us appears frozen and I use a long stick, could I prod that person without him noticing the fkn stick prodding him since he’s frozen or whatever? K fI’m going 60mph relative to the trees, relative to the earths rotation, relative to earths revolution, relative to suns revolution, relative to galaxy’s movement, relative and so and so. Maybe the fastest moving thing IS the most preferential reference frame? Or maybe the CMB? because there’s so much weirdness with no preferential frame

If I went faster than light and caught up to light that left earth 2 million years ago in the year 2 million BC, I’d see light from earth coming from when earths year was 4 million bc. If I go faster than light back to earth will I time travel to 4 million bc simply because I can see some old light or caught to old light? Why is the photon  more important than the atoms that emitted it in the first place, and why does the universe bend reality just so atomic jizz can feel special while atoms themselves can’t?

And technically if we discover a way to go 0.999999% c we would be faster than any science fiction ftl drive ever so long as we are ok with never seeing our families again bcuz time would dilate a billion light years to seconds, so why worry if we will ever reach other stars in our lifetime  at all? And any probe we sent out at 0.99999% c could literally make that journey depending on propulsion efficiency with a small radioactive reactor because it could reach many stars in our neighborhood, take pics and measuarements , and come back to earth and from its perspective it’s hardware only aged a few days and so did its energy use?

Comment: "Has anyone tried gps without considering time dilation to see if it works?" The original GPS had to be replaced because they did not know that they had to take this into account.

Comment: Interesting. I’lledit that out thanks :)

Comment: It feels like you are writing all these questions with good intentions, but: do you really expect to receive good, informative, helpful answers when you write things like "why does the universe bend reality just so atomic jizz can feel special"..?

Comment: Special relativity feels unintuitive for the majority of people the first time they learn it, but so does subtracting negative numbers. I don't think you will be able to grasp how relativity works unless you take a slow, calm, deliberate approach where you try to digest what is actually being said instead of trying to swallow and intuitively digest all these scenarios you have written about all at once

Comment: I asked these scenarios because that’s what will help me. I’ve tried the method you described, literally for 5 years now. I’ve read everything on the topic and watched physicists talk about it. It’s still confusing. It seems to really only make sense in the math but I’m not good at math. There’s just so much weirdness if time dilation does happen. The person accelerating ages slower yes, and when they stop and turn around they age slower,  but what if they never slow down and reverse, and i warp next to them and see them frozen? Could I prod and poke them without them noticing?

Comment: Note that 0.999%c is approximately 1.000%c, which equals c/100, which results is in a time-dilation factor of 1.00005000375 (relatively small for a relativity problem). You probably want 0.999c or 99.9%c. However….. While more dramatic, the arithmetic is unnecessarily complicated and distracts from the physics. Instead, I suggest (3/5)c or (4/5)c, which leads to simpler calculations with fractions.

Comment: Drawing “Spacetime Diagrams” helped me make sense of word problems and clarified the meanings of various formula.

Comment: If you want to figure it out for yourself, the trick is to remember that the underlying principle, from which it all follows, is that the speed of light is the same for everyone. So try to imagine instead a special ball that moves at the same speed for everyone, say ten metres per second. Imagine that I throw the ball at that speed when you are just walking past me at one meter per second following the ball. After a second in my frame, the ball is ten metres away and you are a meter away- what does that tell you?

Comment: "but what if they never slow down and reverse, and i warp next to them and see them frozen? Could I prod and poke them without them noticing?" You are talking as if you are trying to understand the rules of a video game. In our universe, we can never "warp next to" anything, so obviously physics (which describes **our** universe) cannot say anything meaningful about the scenario you are describing. However, if you are stationary next to **anything** then of course your clock and a clock attached to the thing will tick the same rate. Nothing is frozen.

Comment: *So what if I go near speed light and time for me slows.* It doesn’t. There is an inertial reference frame in which, right now, you are moving at 0.999999c. Does time feel slow for you?

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation of "Explain time dilation" is two-fold: explain what it means and try to explain why it happens. In my opinion, "many [...] examples and reasons" would generate confusion, especially if transit times of light signals are involved.

A key idea in Special Relativity is an EVENT: something (like the emission of a flash of light) that can be assigned space and time co-ordinates in any (inertial) frame of reference.

Here is what Time Dilation means... The time interval between two events is greater in a frame of reference in which the events occur in different places than in a frame in which the events occur in the same place.

An example: Two flashes of light are emitted from a space-vehicle travelling at speed $v$ relative to the Earth. In the space-vehicle's frame of reference these events occur in the same place, and the time interval between them is (say) $\Delta T_0$. In the Earth's frame the events occur in different places and the time interval between them is dilated to
$$\Delta T=\frac{\Delta T_0}{\sqrt{(1-v^2/c^2)}}.$$
Most introductions to Special Relativity will justify this equation very nicely by means of a simple thought experiment relying on the speed of light being the same in all inertial frames of reference.

A deeper reason, perhaps, is that the space-time interval, $c^2(\Delta t)^2-(\Delta x)^2-(\Delta y^2)-(\Delta z^2)$, between the same events is the same in all inertial frames – a relativistic invariant.

Comment: If you want to check whether other phenomena are cases of time dilation, make sure that you can identify specific events that can be assigned a time interval between them in a given frame of reference, most importantly the frame which they occur in the same place. I don't suppose that this is what you want to read, but if you really do want to understand time dilation I suggest that you start with the standard approach I've given, however unexciting you may find it.